# JSON data to multiple html tables using JS

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have JSON data for multiple tables on my website. **EVERY TABLE HAS SAME NUMBER OF COLUMNS (2 columns).** I try to minimize function in javascript that displays table with a current JSON data. Do I have to create every table in html or one should be enough  also for the function ? How to take JSON data & create a separate table for them?

**Here is the code**
https://codepen.io/S4UCY/pen/wvGgzmZ

```js
var firstTable = [
    {
        'code': 'blabla',
        'result': 'blablablablablabla',
    },
    {
        'code': 'blabla',
        'result': 'blablablablablabla',
    },
    {
        'code': 'blabla',
        'result': 'blablablabla',
    },
    {
        'code': 'blabla',
        'result': 'blablablablablabla',
    },
    {
        'code': 'blabla',
        'result': 'blablablabla',
    }
]

var secondTable = [
  {
      'code': 'blabla',
      'result': 'blablablablablabla',
  },
  {
      'code': 'blabla',
      'result': 'blablablablablabla',
  },
  {
      'code': 'blabla',
      'result': 'blablablablablabla',
  },
  {
      'code': 'blabla',
      'result': 'blablablablablabla',
  },
  {
      'code': 'blabla',
      'result': 'blablablablablabla',
  }
]

/*
 1. Loop Through Array & Access each value
 2. Create Table Rows & append to table
*/


for (var i in firstTable){
var row = `<tr>
              <td>${firstTable[i].code}</td>
              <td>${firstTable[i].result}</td>
            `
var table = $('#table-body')
table.append(row)
}
```

```css
#title{
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:100;
  font-size:28px;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #fff;
  background-color: #55608f;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #bada55, #5f2c82);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

table {
    width: 500px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

th,
td {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    color: #fff;
}

th {
    text-align: left;
}

thead {
    th {
        background-color: #bada55;
    }
}

tbody {
    tr {
        &:hover {
            background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
        }
    }
    td {
        position: relative;
        &:hover {
            &:before {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                top: -9999px;
                bottom: -9999px;
                background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
                z-index: -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <h1 id="title">List of codes</h1>
   <!-- Table structure here -->
   <table id="our-table">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Code</th>
         <th>Result</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="table-body">
    <!-- Table creates here -->
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: What is the exact expectation? I see the code working fine.  Need clarity. @Sauce

Comment: I want to create a function that inserts as many tables as I want to my HTML code. Tables has same numbers of columns(2).  @Anglesvar Cheenu

Comment: If u want to create number of tables with respect to number of data you have, you should create table each time. You should not define table in your HTML file. You must create a table when you access the data and you should have `id` defined for each table. This is the correct way to approach your expectation.

Comment: The headers of the tables are the same? ("code","result") ?

Comment: Yes the headers are the same in every table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var firstTable = [
    {
        'code': 'blabla',
        'result': 'blablablablablabla',
    },
    {
        'code': 'blabla',
        'result': 'blablablablablabla',
    },
    {
        'code': 'blabla',
        'result': 'blablablabla',
    },
    {
        'code': 'blabla',
        'result': 'blablablablablabla',
    },
    {
        'code': 'blabla',
        'result': 'blablablabla',
    }
]
    var secondTable = [
  {
      'code': 'blabla',
      'result': 'blablablablablabla',
  },
  {
      'code': 'blabla',
      'result': 'blablablablablabla',
  },
  {
      'code': 'blabla',
      'result': 'blablablablablabla',
  },
  {
      'code': 'blabla',
      'result': 'blablablablablabla',
  },
  {
      'code': 'blabla',
      'result': 'blablablablablabla',
  }
]

const addTable = (param)=>{
        let tab = `<table>`;
        let newtab= `<tr><th>Code</th><th>result</th></tr>`;
        for (var i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
             newtab += `<tr><td>${param[i].code}</td><td>${param[i].result}</td></tr>`;
        }
        tab+=`${newtab}</table>`;
        display.innerHTML += tab;
     }
   addTable(firstTable);
   addTable(secondTable);
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```

Create a parameterized function, pass the JSON object of the table you want to create to the function.
Run a loop in the function based on the length of the array of object you passed in.
I placed it in a function so as to enable reuseabilility and to use events to trigger the function whenever you want to add a new table, thereby making it flexible.
I hope this helps.

Comment: It helps but this solution outputs only the last rows from tables.

Comment: oops, I have seen the bug, I will edit the code now to display everything.

Comment: Yep the problem is inside the loop function

Comment: Now I'm just curious. What if I want to have <table> and <tbody> tags for each table in html  and add only <tr> tags to script.

Answer (score 0):

You can define data as mentioned below:

```
var data = [
    [{
        'code': 'blabla',
        'result': 'blablablablablabla',
    },
    {
        'code': 'blabla',
        'result': 'blablablablablabla',
    },
    {
        'code': 'blabla',
        'result': 'blablablabla',
    },
    {
        'code': 'blabla',
        'result': 'blablablablablabla',
    },
    {
        'code': 'blabla',
        'result': 'blablablabla',
    }
],
              //Second Data
[
  {
      'code': 'blabla',
      'result': 'blablablablablabla',
  },
  {
      'code': 'blabla',
      'result': 'blablablablablabla',
  },
  {
      'code': 'blabla',
      'result': 'blablablablablabla',
  },
  {
      'code': 'blabla',
      'result': 'blablablablablabla',
  },
  {
      'code': 'blabla',
      'result': 'blablablablablabla',
  }
]
```

and you can create table each time you enter new data. Something like this.

```
for(let node=0; node<data.length; node++){
  //Here create your table with variable node as your id.
  node.foreach((element)=>{
   //append element data to the table created 
  }
}
```

Hope this Help!!.. Happy Coding!!